# How to get rid of space under columns?

Tags: css, dynamic-columns

I've tried searching but I can't seem to find anything related.

When using columns and having divs auto fill the columns, the bottom has lots of extra space. How do I get rid of it/minimize it?

example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/cj76ienz

edit: I cannot get rid of space on chrome, seems to work fine on firefox and IE

edit2: code

css:

```
 body {
    background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png) ;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    /*-moz-column-fill: auto;*/
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 10px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="columns">
    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
        <p>
            Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
            faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
            convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
        <p>
            Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
            faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
            convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
            sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>  

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula 
            faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc 
            convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
        <p>
            Nullam eget lectus augue. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
            sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
            ac urna vestibulum mattis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
            sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
            ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>  

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
            sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
            ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
        <p>
            Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut 
            sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla 
            ac urna vestibulum mattis. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What extra space? Couldn't see any on your link.

Comment: If you shrink the window enough so there's 3 columns, the mismatch in column heights creates extra space at the very bottom of the pins. Probably should've mentioned this is for chrome.

Comment: add a margin-bottom of 0px to the .pin class -  `.pin { margin-bottom: 0px; }`

Comment: O.o Hokey smokes!! Sorry-- didn't see your comment that this is for Chrome. Was on Firefox, just checked it on Chrome: WAY different. What the heck, Google??!?!?

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Comment: #wrapper margin change somehow removes that weird space in chrome at the bottom in three column setting... I tried replacing the 50px to 0 px and looks pretty nice. Good luck with this issue and if you fix it, we would love to know what it was.